# Derivation of Einstein viscosity formula for dilute suspensions

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

I am looking for a simple derivation of Einstein's viscosity formula for a dilute suspension of small rigid spheres from his PhD thesis in 1905. The formula is

$$\mu_E = \mu(1 + \tfrac52 \alpha) $$

where $\mu_E$ is the Einstein viscosity, $\mu$ is the viscosity of the host liquid and $\alpha$ is the volume fraction of the spheres.

I have been looking for either Einstein's original derivation or a simple derivation of it I can understand as someone with very basic fluid dynamics knowledge. However, all I can find on this is either a qualitative explanation of the importance of the formula, or papers which expand on this formula, or prove it more rigorously and with less assumptions. The former is not particularly useful for my goal, but the latter is too advanced for me to understand at this stage. Could someone either provide me with a derivation, or link me to a source which fits my needs?

Comment: Google Happel and Brenner